# Возможность установки опций при создании нового объекта в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть такой фрагмент кода

```
var draggie = new Draggabilly( elem, {
  axis: 'x';
  containment: '.container';
});
```

Чем является в коде axis и containment? Раньше я подобное делал через аргументы функции, (просто задавая значения) а с таким не сталкивался. В итоге вопрос такой, как таким именно образом при создании объекта передавать ему значения?
[Вот ссылка на код](https://unpkg.com/draggabilly@2.3.0/dist/draggabilly.pkgd.min.js) а вот [на статью с данным кодом](https://draggabilly.desandro.com/).

(Вопрос простой потому что я не из js, простите)

Comment: https://unpkg.com/draggabilly@2.3.0/dist/draggabilly.pkgd.js

Comment: @Igor я имел ввиду каким образом он это сделал? Я в коде не смог быстро разобрать это. Как создать новый класс  с объектами чтоб при их объявления можно было задать опции , то есть передать значение именно как в примере который я привел.

Comment: А я имел в виду, что надо давать ссылку на неминифицированный скрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Чем является в коде axis и containment?

Они являются свойствами параметра `options` функции `Draggabilly`.

```
function Draggabilly( element, options ) {
```

Comment: то есть в js такое делать не надо - 'options {axis: 'x';}'? можно и без упоминания option - '{axis: 'x';}'. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Al-Tamir Не "не надо", а нельзя. С "options" код синтаксически неверен.